# SSIS SSDT - Deploying A DTSX to a Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have been searching for a while on this and have no real direction on what the problem may even be. I haven't done SSIS for about 5 years and even 5 years ago I only did one or two.

I have Visual Studio 2012 on my machine. I installed SSDT so that I could write an SSIS package. I have the package written and working locally but when I try to set up a job in the SQL Agent on the server I get this error after selecting the package:

[image]

I have looked into this error and none of the resolutions I have found are working. My project is already set to not use 64 bit mode. I'm kind of thinking this might have to do with the fact that the version of SQL Server on that machine is just 2008 and that maybe that means it has an incompatible SSIS runtime. I don't know if there is an additional runtime I need to install to get this to work and I don't know if it's backward compatible with the old runtime they are using if that's even the problem.

I can't find any information online about setting up the environment for an SSDT SSIS package..

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a package built against the SQL Server 2012 Integration Services object model. You are attempting to execute it on a 2008 instance. Backwards compatibility is not an option.

You need to either update the 2008 instance to 2012 (there is a licensing change to be aware of) or recreate your package using the 2008 model.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Do you know if I can use the "2008 model" on instances of Visual Studio besides Visual Studio 2008? I only have 2010 and 2012 installed on my local machine.

Comment: billinkc, could I install the DDTS installer on a machine that doesn't necessarily have SQL Server on it at all and run the package from command line? Or would I have to install Visual Studio 2012 AND DDTS to do that? This might be my work around.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps you have to do:
1) Build you package using correct version - Update 2208 Instance to 2012
2) If you have multiple versions install and you try to deploy using .ispac file, it will most likely pick the latest version. To resolve the issue, you have to pick the correct version of Installer by going to where it is installed. In my case it is (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn)